# Why employing getters instead of methods for internal class function in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am reading Flutter documentation for [Read and write Files](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files), and in this very example I don't really "get" the use of a getter.
(I am new to dart)

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return directory.path;
}

Future<File> get _localFile async {
  final path = await _localPath;
  return File('$path/counter.txt');
}

Future<File> writeCounter(int counter) async {
  final file = await _localFile;
  // Write the file.
  return file.writeAsString('$counter');
}
```

Are _localPath and _localFile getters or methods ?
Why not write it this way :

```
Future<String> _localPath() async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return directory.path;
}

Future<File> _localFile() async {
  final path = await _localPath;
  return File('$path/counter.txt');
}

Future<File> writeCounter(int counter) async {
  final file = await _localFile();
  // Write the file.
  return file.writeAsString('$counter');
}
```

Comment: In the particular example where the getters are not part of a public API, it very likely is just a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

getter is a method that doesn't accept any arguments. And that's why is accessed like any other field and not a method. Basically, it can always be replaced with a method with zero arguments but a getter may be a more elegant way in some cases. For example: your class have a field that holds a date of birth. And you create a getter `age` instead of a method `calculateAge()`. **You don't really have to, but you can if you prefer**

Comment: I understand it very clearly in your example.

I think I am puzzled in this case, because these getters are used internally in the class.